# Linq Query not returning previous 6 months

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query returning previous 12 months just fine

```
var Last12query = from ech in this.dbContext.EmployeeCheckHistories
                          where ech.CompanyID == GlobalVariables.CompanyID &&
                          ech.Employees.ClientID == GlobalVariables.Client
                          group ech by ech.CheckDate.Value.AddMonths(-12).Month into echG
                          orderby echG.Key ascending
                          select echG;
```

But when I try to pull the previous 6 months it returns the same data

```
var Last6query = from ech in this.dbContext.EmployeeCheckHistories
                          where ech.CompanyID == GlobalVariables.CompanyID &&
                          ech.Employees.ClientID == GlobalVariables.Client
                          group ech by ech.CheckDate.Value.AddMonths(-6).Month into echG
                          orderby echG.Key ascending
                          select echG;
```

I'm unsure why the data returned would still be 12 months worth.

This is the JSON i'm getting returned

```
[{"SeriesName":["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"],"Value":[160536.62000,115787.74000,300994.32000,72237.43000,73189.97000,61357.57000,43790.03000,31074.86000,58405.69000,64351.36000,82715.84000,78962.98000]},
{"SeriesName":["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"],"Value":[43790.03000,31074.86000,58405.69000,64351.36000,82715.84000,78962.98000,160536.62000,115787.74000,300994.32000,72237.43000,73189.97000,61357.57000]}]
```

Comment: If I'm reading it correctly, the code shifts the date of the check backs by 6 or 12 months,  it doesn't filter by date. shouldn't there be dates in the where clauses?

Comment: It should group the checks by date for the previous 6 months.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are not filtering the query (where clause) just grouping, so you always  get all rows grouped by month.
Also subtracting 12 monts from a date you get the same month one year before, so in your case when you get only month number for grouping it doesn't have any effect.

If you want data for the last N months from today, you should have something like this:

```
var dateLimit = DateTime.Today().AddMonths(-N);
...
where ech.CheckDate>=dateLimit
group ech by ech.CheckDate.Month()
...
```

Comment: There's no need to make `dateLimit` a separate variable since the query is going to be translated to SQL. I would just keep the `DateTime.Today().AddMonths(-N)` inline.

Comment: Maybe.. I'm used to prepare calcs out of the query for avoiding exceptions about linq to entities not being able to translate the operation, as happens with ToString(), but in this case it will work ok inline. By the way please mark the answer as solved if you can. Regards

Answer (score 1):

By your Linq written for `Last12query` and `Last6query` the use of Group by is done wrong, in the query for `Last6query` you just shifted the data to 6 months before. not the data for the month itself(yo wont get proper data for any specific month),for 12 month data it will be fine because you shifted it by a year. you can see this in your data. coz `december-6 months` gonna be `june`, so (any month - 6 month) will be some month.

So doing subtraction of month is not the solution, do this to your query.

```
var Last6query = from ech in this.dbContext.EmployeeCheckHistories
                      where ech.CompanyID == GlobalVariables.CompanyID &&
                      ech.Employees.ClientID == GlobalVariables.Client
                      where ech.CheckDate.Value.Month>DateTime.Today().AddMonths(-6)
                      group ech by ech.CheckDate.Value.Month into echG
                      orderby echG.Key ascending
                      select echG;
```

and do the same for 12 month also. because you are not checking with month and year, otherwise it will show the year wrong(if the year is 2015 , it will show 2014 in results).

```
  var Last12query = from ech in this.dbContext.EmployeeCheckHistories
                      where ech.CompanyID == GlobalVariables.CompanyID &&
                      ech.Employees.ClientID == GlobalVariables.Client
                      where ech.CheckDate.Value.Month>DateTime.Today().AddMonths(-12)
                      group ech by ech.CheckDate.Value.Month into echG
                      orderby echG.Key ascending
                      select echG;
```